# how can i make a bot status with member counter?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i wanted to set a member counter status for my bot
the code is:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      targetGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('I Pasted my Guild ID Here')
      if(targetGuild) {
          client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: targetGuild.memberCount + 'Members', type: 'WATCHING' }, status: 'online'  })
                .then(console.log)
                .catch(console.error);
      }
    }, 1000 * 60 * 5);

});
```

And the error is:

```
client.user.setPresence(...).then is not a function
```

Comment: What discord.js version are you using?

Comment: i'm using version.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In discord.js v13, `setPresence` returns a [`ClientPresence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientPresence), not a Promise as in [v12](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence), so there is no `.then()` method.

Comment: Do you know how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using djs v13 you need to use:

```js
client.user.setPresence({ 
activities: [{ name: `${targetGuild.memberCount} Members`, type: 'WATCHING' }], 
status: 'online'
})
```

And also there is no `.then()` method because in discord.js v13 `setPresence` doesn't return a `Promise` but `ClientPresence`

Comment: Thank You! It worked. But one more problem. I have 14 members but in my but in my bot status it writes 5 members

Comment: And the type of status is written "Playing" instead of "Watching"

Comment: Sorry that I'm bothering you but it says "message is not defined".

Comment: @Pooyan oops, change `message.guild` to `targetGuild`, my bad again :< (I changed my code again)

Comment: @Pooyan np, can you please mark this answer as correct?

Comment: i don't have enough reputations. sorry to ask, but is there a way that, in the bot's status, it writes only members count, and not include bots?

Comment: @Pooyan to mark answer as correct you don't need reputation, there is gray check mark you need to click on. Also you can get only users count using `targetGuild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size`

Comment: I marked your answer as correct. and I did what you said for my second question: it wrote 0 members and did not filter correctly.

Comment: @Pooyan then you should ask it as new question, your original question was already answered

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69787919/how-can-i-do-something-that-in-my-bots-status-it-writes-watching-member-cou