# Filter out bots from member count in client status

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter, discord, discord.js

I want to make my bot activity say **"Watching + Member Count (not include bots)"**.

I did some steps, here is my code:

```js
client.once('ready', () => { 
        setInterval(() => {
          targetGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('My Guild ID Here')
          client.user.setPresence({ 
            activities: [{ name: `${targetGuild.memberCount} Users`, type: 'WATCHING' }], 
            status: 'online'
            });
        }, 1000 * 60 * 5);
    
    });
```

The thing that I need is to set a filter that it calculate members only, not bots.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GuildMemberManager#fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) to fetch all members, then use [Collection#partition()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=partition) to split the member collection into `bots` and `humans`. Use `humans.size` to display the user count as you intend. You can also [Collection#filter()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) to filter the member collection to just the humans, however I use partition in this example to have access to both parties in one function call.

```js
client.once('ready', async() => { 
   targetGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('My Guild ID Here');
   try {
      const [bots, humans] = (await targetGuild.members.fetch())
         .partition(member => member.user.bot);
      setInterval(() => {
         client.user.setPresence({ 
            activities: [
               { 
                  name: `${humans.size} Users`, 
                  type: 'WATCHING' 
               }
            ], 
            status: 'online'
         });
      }, 1000 * 60 * 5);
   } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
   }
});
```

Comment: I got an error at first:
`Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time.`
and I tried again, nothing happened.

Comment: You need to enable the guild member's intent to be able to fetch members.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Read [This Article on Gateway Intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents)

Answer (score 0):

In discord.js v13 the member counting with bot filtering should look like this:

```js
   setInterval(() => {
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD_ID');
          let humanMembers = guild.members.cache.filter(
            (user) => !user.user.bot
          );
          const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL_ID');
          channel.setName(`Member Count Test: ${humanMembers.size.toString()}`);
        }, 60000);
});
```